# SpriteKit camera actions being very jerky/laggy

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I'm using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.2.1, testing on an iPhone 6s running iOS 10.2.

I'm simply attempting to rotate an SKCameraNode at a rate that is slowing down (I.E. it has both an angular velocity and acceleration).

This is my current solution, and yes I know it's weird:

```
 cam.run(
    SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.run
                {
                    self.cam.run(SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 0.0, duration: 0.7, shortestUnitArc: true))
                },
            SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1)])))
```

The camera's zRotation starts at some non-zero place, and then this is called. It then calls the SKAction.rotate part every 0.1 seconds. It's not shown here, but I have it terminate after 3 seconds.

This provides the exact effect that I want, because every time the SKAction is called, the zRotation is closer to its 0.0, but the time it needs to take to get there stays at 0.7, so the rate at which it approaches 0.0 slows down.

HOWEVER, 1 of 3 things happen from this:

1. It works perfectly as intended
2. It feels like it stops and continues every 0.1 seconds
3. The camera just immediately and completely stops functioning as a camera as soon as the SKAction is called, and the player is just stuck looking at the same spot till the cameras are switched.

I tried reducing the waitForDuration from 0.1 to 0.01 but then it always does option 3.

Is there some sort of "rules of execution" that I'm not following when it comes to using cameras?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer from 0x141E looks good for this specific case. But if you want a better generic animation system let me plug my [animation library](https://github.com/j-h-a/Animation). It lets you trigger animations with a closure that gets called in sync with the display refresh, inside there you do your calculations and set whatever values you want. For example in your case it would be as simple as: `rotation = startAngle <~~ Curve.parabolicDeceleration[progress] ~~> 0.0`. The `<~~` and `~~>` operators are part of the library, for doing interpolation between two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single `rotate(toAngle:)` action that decelerates when the camera's `zRotation` is close to the ending angle and setting the `timingMode` property to `.easeOut`. For example,

```
cam.zRotation = CGFloat.pi
let action = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: 0, duration: duration, shortestUnitArc: true)

// Slows when zRotation is near 0
action.timingMode = .easeOut

cam.run(action)
```

Alternatively, you can define your own timing function to customize the ease-out behavior by replacing `timingMode` statement with

```
action.timingFunction = {
    time in
    // Custom ease-out, modify this as needed
    return 1-pow(1-time, 5)
 }
```

Moreover, you can use the following to calculate the action's duration so the angular velocity and acceleration are consistent regardless of the starting angle (i.e., the amount of rotation)

```
let duration = TimeInterval(normalizedArcFromZero(angle:cam.zRotation)) * 3

func normalizedArcFromZero(angle:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let diff = angle.mod(dividingBy:CGFloat.pi*2)
    let arc = CGFloat.pi - (diff + CGFloat.pi).mod(dividingBy:2 * CGFloat.pi)
    return abs(arc)/CGFloat.pi
}
```

Lastly, since the above requires a modulo function that performs a "floored" division (instead of Swift's `truncatingRemainder`), you'll need to add this to your project

```
extension CGFloat {
    func mod(dividingBy x:CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return self - floor(self/x) * x
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! One question - is the input of the timingFunction going to be the time since the beginning of the SKAction?

Comment: @MarshallD `time` starts at 0 and ends at 1. Similarly, the closure needs to return a value that starts at 0 and ends at 1. If you plot the expression in my answer with `time` incrementing from 0 to 1, you'll see what an ease-out function looks like. You can then adjust the function, accordingly.